# Passing both props.children and a component as prop in React/Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-props, higher-order-components

User.tsx is a kind of navigation bar that passes all children components through via {props.children}. I also want to pass a breadcrumb component through to it as well but I'm getting an error that says:

> JSX element type 'props.component' does not have any construct or call
> signatures

Layout.tsx:

```
 import UserShell from "./account/User
 import Breadcrumb from "./navigation/Breadcrumb";
 <User component={Breadcrumb}>{props.children}</User>;
```

User.tsx:

```
type ShellProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
  component?: React.ComponentType;


export default function UserShell(props: ShellProps) {
 return (
    <>
      <props.component />
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//error is here

      <div>{props.children}</div>
    </>
}
```

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Your type says `props.component` might be undefined, but your code doesn't check for that case. What would you like to do if no component is passed in? If you just want to render nothing, then do `{props.component && <props.component />}`

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'

type ShellProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    component?: React.ComponentType;
}

function UserShell(props: ShellProps) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.component ? <props.component /> : null}
            <div>{props.children}</div>
        </>
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAZQAskAbZgBRzAGc4BeOAN6k4IuGgbBmAEyIA7AFyJiMAHTJ0MAHIQptAD5KNa5dt0BtALoBuYaLS5IspLJgB+ReowqAwg4hOXABVqJBsAX3JMAFdZDGB-OABVLiQoRhZmAAowTi5FdNYOCG4ASkFbESIYKKhZOEyK0REAHgA+RqamgRzirhV7cH9neFc4Zp7ufr8A+AB6VrhFWSjWCM71salgADdW7tz+iWk5MObZrd2O0TP2sKA)

you probably need to capitalize the component (Component)

Answer (score 0):

try updating to this

Layout.tsx:

```
 import UserShell from "./account/User
 import Breadcrumb from "./navigation/Breadcrumb";
 <User Breadcrumb={Breadcrumb}>{props.children}</User>; //use Breadcrumb or Component (capital C)
```

User.tsx

```
type ShellProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
  Breadcrumb?: React.ElementType; //covers all elements


export default function UserShell({Breadcrumb, children}) {
 return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumb/>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
}
```